# PostgreSQL 9.6.17 COALESCE function error

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.6, type-conversion, coalesce

I'm trying a SQL query with the function `COALESCE` in PostgreSQL 9.6.17, but it produces an error:

> invalid syntax for type double precision: ""

Example query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(date_part('year', s.date_pp),'')
FROM public.sendoc s.
```

This query is working on PostgreSQL 9.3.17.

How to get around the error at the server DB level without changing the source code of the program?

Comment: I am really surprised this worked in 9.3

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name There might have been some custom implicit type casts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can "fix" this without changing your query or going back to Postgres 9.3, where apparently type casting rules were more relaxed.

`date_part()` returns a floating point value, and in the absence of an implicit type cast Postgres tries to convert the other operand of `coalesce()` to a compatible value, and an empty string (`''`) cannot be so converted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I understand it, in the Postgres settings, there is no way to configure loyalty when an implicit type for resolve "fix"?

Comment: In my view, it was a bug that was fixed post-9.3. I don't know of a way to undo that in Postgres. If you're looking for a database that's quite liberal with type casts, try MySQL (though it'll probably hurt you in many other ways).

Comment: @ИванЛинюшин: the correct fix is, to fix your query, not Postgres (because 9.6 behaves correctly, the fact that this worked in 9.3 was a bug to begin with).

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL CAST To Convert a Value of One Type to Another.
SELECT COALESCE(CAST(date_part('year', s.date_pp) as VARCHAR),'')
FROM public.sendoc s